# Using webspace instead of a server to host my application data.

Tags: android

1) I am new to server side programming in Java and Android so please bear with me.

2) Is there a difference between webspace(Reseller account) I purchased with BlueHost and a server used for hosting application data in Android.

3)I have bought some webspace (Reseller account) I want to know if I can use this webspace to host my application data, like if I want to upload images from my application and fetch the same in the same application, generally speaking text and multimedia.(How do I overcome the ftp Uname and Password barrier if I allow the users of my application to upload data?) If so please guide me to some beginner tutorials for the same.

4)How do we use XML and JSON for client server communication, is it applicable in my case. Tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "Webspace" I presume it is one of the Web hosting setup (WAMP or LAMP) and it includes at least: some disk space (create files) and a programming platform (php, js etc).

The typical implementation is to create a php script which acts as a service, i.e exposes the upload and download functionality. It may include code for asking user to log-in before doing anything.

You may also setup a database (typically MySQL) for saving structured information apart from files.

Other variable is communication mode, it depends on the complexity of communication. For simple get and post requests even HTTP would suffice (REST), if you transfer a little more complex data such as names, tags, location etc with images, you might want to go for JSON. Finally if you want to implement it in  heavyweight standard, you can use XML (SOAP etc).

I'm sure there are many php based frameworks and parsing libraries that you can use for a quick web service setup.

Comment: Yes webspace is the same. It is the one which I have used to host my website and make it available to public on the internet. I should look up XML SOAP on the internet now. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Can you guide me to some tutorials? Where to start and all that?

Comment: @ChronicallyInsane. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/index.html